# Can't get librosa load a wav file

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I got an audio dataset of many wav files and tired to use librosa to edit, but I have trouble reading some certain files by using librosa.load.Could someone help me figure it out?

here is my code:

```
import librosa
sound_clip = librosa.load('audio/fold1/180937-7-3-10.wav')
print(sound_clip)
```

here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-93fe2f032e98> in <module>()
----> 1 sound_clip = librosa.load('audio/fold1/180937-7-3-10.wav')
      2 print(sound_clip)

/home/uri7910/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow011/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.pyc in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype)
    107 
    108     y = []
--> 109     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
    110         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    111         n_channels = input_file.channels

/home/uri7910/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow011/lib/python2.7/site-packages/audioread/__init__.pyc in audio_open(path)
    100         from . import maddec
    101         try:
--> 102             return maddec.MadAudioFile(path)
    103         except DecodeError:
    104             pass

/home/uri7910/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow011/lib/python2.7/site-packages/audioread/maddec.pyc in __init__(self, filename)
     24     def __init__(self, filename):
     25         self.fp = open(filename, 'rb')
---> 26         self.mf = mad.MadFile(self.fp)
     27         if not self.mf.total_time(): # Indicates a failed open.
     28             raise UnsupportedError()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MadFile'
```

Comment: This is the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819102/could-someone-tell-me-why-i-cant-load-some-certian-wav-files-by-librosa-alway)  you asked yesterday.  It does have some more detail, which is good.  But you can, and should edit your original question.

Comment: Thank you. I have deleted the old question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing line is:

```
self.mf = mad.MadFile(self.fp)
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MadFile'

This looks to be a problem with the [pyMad library](http://spacepants.org/src/pymad/).  Would suggest looking into upgrading or reinstalling. that library.  If that fails you might want to [raise a bug](https://github.com/jaqx0r/pymad/issues).

Comment: I fixed the problem by uninstall the module 'mad'. It seems that there are some conflicts between 'mad' and 'librosa'. Is this a bug?

Comment: That lib is this: https://github.com/fchauvel/MAD.  This library has nothing to do with pymad, so yes it was the wrong one, and not a bug.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot !